# Incorrect time while copy pasting a date time value using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am getting a time value from one sheet (A) and putting in another sheet (B), some 32 minutes are getting added to the time value in sheet (B). Here is the code:

```
function pushRow() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var s1 = ss.getSheetByName ("Sheet1");
   var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
   var data = s1.getRange("A2:C2").getValues();
   s2.appendRow(data[0]);

}
```

Here is the screenshot of both the sheets:

- Sheet (A):

[image]

- Sheet (B):

[image]

Comment: `Indian Standard Time is UTC+05:30).` - sounds like you get the 30 minutes plus the age of the time stamp

Comment: In the script editor, click "File" -> "Project Properties" and look at the time zone setting.  Then in the spreadsheet, click "File" -> "Spreadsheet Settings" and see if the time zone is different.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the validation in the time column in Sheet(A)

Comment: check if `getDisplayValues` returns the correct value

Comment: @SandyGood: Time zone is same at both in script editor as well as in Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Ritz: getDisplayValues works perfectly. Thanks a Ton! Although it's still weird why getValues is getting wrong time.